# How to append data, when colspan applied by datatable when no data available as a result from jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to append the rows after message shown as No Data available from datatable by default. I need to redraw the table but due to colspan applied with that message column can't append the columns dynamically. How to remove that colspan and add the columns to the row. Here I have tried:

```
    var row = $("#Schedule-datatable tbody tr:last-child").removeAttr("style").removeAttr("class").clone(true);
        $("#Schedule-datatable tbody tr").remove();
        var dt = $("#Schedule-datatable").dataTable({
            "bRetrieve": true
        }).api();
        dt.clear();
        dt.draw(false);

//Here I'm binding the columns inside loop for list of rows.

    {
    dt.row.add($(row)).draw();
                row = $("#Schedule-datatable tbody tr:last-child").clone(true);
    }
```

If I get the message as No data available , I can't again bind the list of items as row again. How to fix this.Any solutions welcomed.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this so its easy to understand?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you add new rows the *"No data available"* message will automatically disappear.

Comment: No It wont disappeared that's the problem I faced as of now @davidkonrad

Comment: Why are you cloning rows ...? What is the purpose with all that? It seem to me you are doing something totally weird, but perhaps you have some kind of reason to do so ..? A simple `dt.row.add(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']).draw()` (dont know how many columns you have) will make the *"No data available"* message to disappear ...